# how do i user Jquery selector for odd and even rows generated by php code?

Tags: php, jquery, css

So basically i would like to color the comments from users so it look clear and separate.
The comments is coming from the database, the php codes will generate the comments in a HTML page. And i am using CSS and Jquery as well. I have tried but my codes don't work, any idea?

HTML/PHP:

```
    <? 
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($comment);++$i)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($comment);
?>  
        <div class = "comment">
        <p> <? echo $row['c_content']; ?>  by <? echo $row['c_name']; ?> </p>
        </div>
        <?}?>
```

CSS:

```
.comment
{
    background-color:#fff;     
}

.alt
{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".comment:odd").addClass('alt');
});
```

So as you can see, I want the "odd" comment class have color #CCC, and the even have #FFF... Please help

Comment: If you're generating the table with PHP and it's not going to be shifted around 'n' stuff, you could add "odd" and "even" classes in your loop in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use jQuery here. Use CSS:

```
.comment:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.comment:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Unrelated, but worth noting is that unless you're using both associate and numerical keys to access your mysql result, you should get into the habit of using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` or you are always using twice as much memory.

Comment: Thanks for your time!
But just in case if i would like to stick with jquery, what mistake i made>?

Comment: You could try adding `!important` to the `.alt` class or replacing the class instead of adding to it.

Comment: `!important` is icky stuff you should avoid unless you absolutely MUST use it. Just make it more specific; for example if these elements are divs, the CSS becomes `div.alt` which is more specific than just `.comment`. So-called "specificity wars" are also icky, but for an example like this, it's the right way to go!